# Python - KeyError: 'x'

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, keyerror

This is my number2text code:

```
num = raw_input "insert an int"
p = len(num) 
if p == 1:
    print numbers[num]
if p == 2:
    print tens[num[0]] + numbers_teeens[num[1]]
if p == 3:
    print numbers_hundreds[num[0]] + tens[num[1]] + numbers_teeens[num[2]]
if p == 4:
print numbers_thousands[num[0]]+ numbers_hundreds[num[1]] + tens[num[2]] + numbers_teeens[num[3]]
if p == 5:
print numbers_ten_thousands[num[0]] + numbers_thousands[num[1]]+ numbers_hundreds[num[2]] + tens[num[3]] + numbers_teeens[num[4]]
if p == 6:
print numbers_hundred_thousands[num[0]] + numbers_ten_thousands[num[1]] + numbers_thousands[num[2]]+ numbers_hundreds[num[3]] + tens[num[4]] + numbers_teeens[num[5]]
```

And these are my dictionaries:

```
numbers = {1: 'One', 2: 'Two', 3: 'Three', 4: 'Four', 5: 'Five', 6: 'Six', 7: 'Seven', 8: 'Eight', 9: 'Nine'}
tens = {1: 'Ten', 2: 'Twenty', 3: 'Thirty', 4: 'Forty', 5: 'fifty', 6: 'Sixty', 7: 'Seventy', 8: 'Eighty', 9: 'Ninety'}
numbers_teens = {1: 'Eleven', 2: 'Twelve', 3: 'Thirteen', 4: 'Fourteen', 5: 'Fifteen', 6: 'Sixteen', 7: 'Seventeen', 8: 'Eighteen', 9: 'Nineteen'}
numbers_teeens = {0 : '', 1: 'One', 2: 'Two', 3: 'Three', 4: 'Four', 5: 'Five', 6: 'Six', 7: 'Seven', 8: 'Eight', 9: 'Nine', 11: 'Eleven', 12: 'Twelve', 13: 'Thirteen', 14: 'Fourteen', 15: 'Fifteen', 16: 'Sixteen', 17: 'Seventeen', 18: 'Eighteen', 19: 'Nineteen'}
numbers_hundreds = {}
numbers_thousands = {}
numbers_ten_thousands = {}
numbers_teen_thousands = {}
numbers_hundred_thousands = {}

#Creates lists
for k,v in numbers.items():
    numbers_hundreds.update({k: v.title() + ' Hundred'}) 
    numbers_thousands.update({k: v.title() + ' Thousand and'})  

for k1,v1 in tens.items():
    numbers_ten_thousands.update({k1: v1.title()})

for kt,vt in numbers_teens.items():
    numbers_teen_thousands.update({kt: vt.title() + ' Thousand'})

for k2,v2 in numbers_hundreds.items():
    numbers_hundred_thousands.update({k2: v2.title() + ' Thousand'})
```

If my input is `32` for example. I am getting this error `KeyError: '2'`

I saw some other posts, but they were only about `KeyError: x` (without the `''`), and the ones that did have `''`, were only because someone forgot to put an `x` key in the dict.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the error message says the missing key is `'2'`, in other words, a string.  You have integers as keys, like `2`.  You can either create your keys as strings to begin with, or convert your string data into ints to do the lookup.

Comment: I made `num_i = int(num)` but when I tried to input `34` it told me `TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

Comment: Then you didn't do `int(num)`, you did `int[num]` (I think).

Comment: And I know that I still didn't do everything that is after `p ==3`

Comment: This is not a good place to get a chat going about your program. You can't do `num[i]` if num is an int.

Comment: I don't have `num[i]` in my code... I am only asking: How do I fix `TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

Comment: You'll have to try to understand: you have a few places where you are trying to extract a digit of an int with something like `num[1]` or `num_i[0]`, etc. You can't do that. The full error report will tell you exactly which line has the problem.

Comment: Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It's saying *KeyError: '2'*.
I think you got mixed up.
Your number2text code is wrong.
Instead of 'tens[num[0]]' consider '***tens[int(str(num)[0])]***'

so if you put the two texts together you get:

```
numbers = {1: 'One', 2: 'Two', 3: 'Three', 4: 'Four', 5: 'Five', 6: 'Six', 7:           'Seven', 8: 'Eight', 9: 'Nine'}
tens = {1: 'Ten', 2: 'Twenty', 3: 'Thirty', 4: 'Forty', 5: 'fifty', 6: 'Sixty', 7: 'Seventy', 8: 'Eighty', 9: 'Ninety'}
numbers_teens = {1: 'Eleven', 2: 'Twelve', 3: 'Thirteen', 4: 'Fourteen', 5: 'Fifteen', 6: 'Sixteen', 7: 'Seventeen', 8: 'Eighteen', 9: 'Nineteen'}
numbers_teeens = {0 : '', 1: 'One', 2: 'Two', 3: 'Three', 4: 'Four', 5: 'Five', 6: 'Six', 7: 'Seven', 8: 'Eight', 9: 'Nine', 11: 'Eleven', 12: 'Twelve', 13: 'Thirteen', 14: 'Fourteen', 15: 'Fifteen', 16: 'Sixteen', 17: 'Seventeen', 18: 'Eighteen', 19: 'Nineteen'}
numbers_hundreds = {}
numbers_thousands = {}
numbers_ten_thousands = {}
numbers_teen_thousands = {}
numbers_hundred_thousands = {}

#Creates lists
for k,v in numbers.items():
    numbers_hundreds.update({k: v.title() + ' Hundred'}) 
    numbers_thousands.update({k: v.title() + ' Thousand and'})  

for k1,v1 in tens.items():
    numbers_ten_thousands.update({k1: v1.title()})

for kt,vt in numbers_teens.items():
    numbers_teen_thousands.update({kt: vt.title() + ' Thousand'})

for k2,v2 in numbers_hundreds.items():
    numbers_hundred_thousands.update({k2: v2.title() + ' Thousand'})

num = raw_input "insert an int"
p = len(num) 
if p == 1:
    print int(numbers[int(str(num))]
if p == 2:
    print tens[int(str(int(str(num)))[0])] + numbers_teeens[int(str(num))[1]]
if p == 3:
    print numbers_hundreds[int(str(num))[0]] + tens[int(str(num))[1]] + numbers_teeens[int(str(num))[2]]
if p == 4:
    print numbers_thousands[int(str(num))[0]]+ numbers_hundreds[int(str(num))[1]] + tens[int(str(num))[2]] + numbers_teeens[int(str(num))[3]]
if p == 5:
    print numbers_ten_thousands[int(str(num))[0]] + numbers_thousands[int(str(num))[1]]+ numbers_hundreds[int(str(num))[2]] + tens[int(str(num))[3]] + numbers_teeens[int(str(num))[4]]
if p == 6:
    print numbers_hundred_thousands[int(str(num))[0]] + numbers_ten_thousands[int(str(num))[1]] + numbers_thousands[int(str(num))[2]]+ numbers_hundreds[int(str(num))[3]] + tens[int(str(num))[4]] + numbers_teeens[int(str(num))[5]]
```